# Can a Facebook Page's stream be retrieved as JSON without user authentication?

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api, stream, feed, access-token

I'm attempting to display the contents of a Facebook page wall on an external website.

Ideally, I'd retrieve the data as a JSON object but this appears to require user authentication.

How can I retrieve this information without having a user to use for authentication?

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you get a public Facebook page's feed using Graph API without asking a user to allow?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9373645/can-you-get-a-public-facebook-pages-feed-using-graph-api-without-asking-a-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an app and [authenticate as the app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/).

If you're using one of the Facebook SDKs, you can skip the authentication step and just pass it your app ID and secret.